# C# - Convert Int to KeyValue to String

Tags: c#, string, int, key-value

I have a value of key in file.
How I can convert this value to string representing this key?

When I have an event:

```
  void text_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            this.text_button.Clear();
            this.text_button.Text = e.KeyValue.ToString();
        }
```

I do this. But now i dont have KeyEventArgs but int.

So, how to convert int to KeyValue to string? :/

Thanks for reading, 
Greetings!

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I think it is not obvious what you want to do.

Comment: Any object or built-in supports the method .ToString() or you can override it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some conversion code for `Keys`, `int`, and `string`:

```
        var key = Keys.Control;
        var keyInt = (int)key;
        var keyStr = ((Keys)keyInt).ToString();
        var key2 = (Keys) Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), keyStr);

        Console.WriteLine(key == key2);
        Console.WriteLine(keyStr);
```

Comment: i get the error "type or namespace Keys could not be found" how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 5):

Use `KeyData` instead of `KeyValue`. Also, you don't need to clear the `TextBox` as you're already updating instead of appending.

```
void text_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
     this.text_button.Text = e.KeyData.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to convert int to a string in another place, when i cant use KeyEventArgs. Anyway thanks for repair my code. :)